# Ruud furnace blower fails to start

Tags: hvac

I have a Ruud furnace that fires up and runs for about 3 mins and then shuts down, The blower never comes on.

I do not get any voltage to the motor. I have two limit control switches, one is in the cavity of the  housing and is about 16 ohms. The other had a push button reset and sits just above the burners. That one reads 0 ohms.

I don't want to just shot gun this thing.

My possibilities are the limit switches or the board.

Comment: "*My possibilities are the limit switches or the board.*" Do you have a specific question about the  limit switches or the board.

Comment: What model is your furnace?

Comment: You say it "fires up and runs" - what does this mean exactly? Does the draft inducer spin and the pressure switch function? Does the gas valve open and the burners ignite? The point at which the furnace fails to progress in its startup will tell you what needs to be fixed. Without more accurate information, it is difficult to say if there is a problem with your blower, or a different sensor/switch problem that prevents the logic board from powering the blower.